# Why is the copy command in the post build event in my proj file not working on build server?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, copy, csproj

I have a C# project that I am trying to build locally as well as on the build server. In the post build event section in my csproj file, I have a copy command that copies a file from one folder to another. The copy command works locally but it does not work on the build server. This works if I go to the build server and manually execute the command through the command prompt.

Copy command in csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<PostBuildEvent>copy /y "$(TargetPath)" "C:\CommerceSuitePackage"</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I noticed that there is a warning message that says: "The OutputPath property is not set for project". This may or may not be related to the issue.

Below is the screenshot for the build configuration for the csproj file.

[image]

Please suggest what might be wrong.

Comment: You should specify what 'does not work' means. Error message, exit code, ... Same for 'execute the command through the command prompt':  $(TargetPath) isn't something you can use on the command prompt so I assume you're manually replacing that with some path. Is that exactly the same path as the value TargetPath has in the project? And what happens when you build the entire project manually on the build server (if you can do that)?

Comment: Maybe the copy command just failed. 1. Check the sever build log. It probably contains the causes. 2. Try simple command like "ping localhost" and check if the log contains it to make sure the postbuildevent is called.